# How to refer to an ever expanding column of data automatically?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a column of data which contains a list of unique IDs.

There are a set of tabs which then uses this list to display various associated data against each ID.

Presently, any time a new ID is added, I must manually add the new ID to each subsidiary tab in order to get the data.

I'd like to do this automatically, such that an addition to the master list populates into the tabs. I don't know of a way with my (limited) knowledge of google sheets to do this, however- any ideas? :)

The basic way to do this is to initialize the first column in each tab with a simple '='Master List'!A1' and copy it down. This works, but if you sort the master list, it plays havoc with tabs.

Difficult to explain, but something like:

```
Master List tab
12
13
35
111

Data Tab #1
12 Orange
13 Pear
35 Apple
111 Dragonfruit

Data Tab #2
12 Orange
13 Green
35 Red
111 White

Data Tab #3
12 Tart
13 Juicy
35 Crisp
111 Dried
```

...now, if I add 140 to the Master List, I must (currently) manually populate Data Tab #1-3. I'd like it to populate automatically.

I update the Master List, and all associated Tabs show the new entry.

Answer (score 0):

In each Data Tab, instead of

> '='Master List'!A1' and copy it down

try

```
=arrayformula('Master List'!A1:A)
```

This is an array formula and does not need to be copied down. It will populate the entire column with the IDs.

This works nicely too:

```
={'Master List'!A:A}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give these a go tonight.

Thank you.

Comment: These work great for copying over the list, but the tabs are still sorted with the Master is sorted, unfortunately. I presume that is unavoidable?

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=INDIRECT("'Master List'!A1:A"&COUNTA('Master List'!A1:A))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give all of these a shot this evening. Appreciated!

Comment: As above, this works great for copying over the list, but the tabs are still sorted with the Master is sorted, unfortunately. I presume that is unavoidable?

Comment: depends... but most likely yes in your case coz you reuse IDs for different items

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help!